# Attributing a single source in a blog post

Tags: blog, ap-style

Let's say you're writing a blog post based on a single source, like a podcast. You use several quotes from the podcast for the post.

Is it necessary to cite the single podcast source every time you use a direct quote (or paraphrased content)?

Or is introducing the podcast in the first paragraph enough, with the assumption that the following new quotes are from the same source?

I can't find a specific rule for this in the CP stylebook. Is there one for AP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on how your blog is setup.  If the blog is one page that is searchable then I think your suggestion of once in the first paragraph is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you have to *attribute* the quotes, even if you don't have to cite them flat out.

So your first mention would be something like:

> This scene was in fact shot in Seville, Spain rather than Morocco (*Fire and Lunch,* 7/15/06).

And then subsequent mentions:

> Young Ned's rush into the Tower of Joy is halted by Bran's time-traveled shout. If Bran hadn't distracted him, as *Fire and Lunch* suggests, he might have gotten there soon enough to get help for Lyanna.